# Give an enumerate list a name and reference

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

I would like to have a list that is referenced later by a label.

> Table 1: List of steps needed to be taken
>
> 1. Do A
> 2. Do B
> 3. Do C
>
> As seen in Table 1

And I would like to be able to reference externally.

I have got the `enumerate` down and trying to insert a label I do the following:

```
\begin{enumerate} \caption{List of steps needed to be taken}\label{dolist}
  \item Do A.
  \item Do B.
  \item Do C.
\end{enumerate}

As seen in Table~\ref{dolist}.
```

This of course throws an error since `\caption` cannot be included in this way. Getting rid of it still only gives me the reference for the section rather than the enumerate.

Comment: Should this be really referenced as a table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just place it in a `table` environment – no need to put a table in there. It can be (almost) anything and the caption still calls it a table :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{List of steps needed to be taken}\label{dolist}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Do A.
    \item Do B.
    \item Do C.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{table}

As seen in Table~\ref{dolist}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this float away then?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer very likely :) But why shouldn't it float when it has a caption?

Comment: Well, a caption is not necessarily meant for a floating environment

Comment: @ChristianHupfer only floats have them (unless you load the `caption` package or a non-standard class) and I don't think this is by chance. Anyway, there are plenty of questions and solutions for prohibit floating of floats…

Comment: Descriptive text (and that's in a caption) is not bound to a floating stuff in the sense of LaTeX. You could provide such a caption to anything, however, with more less efforts, of course.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer (this starts to become a different discussion altogether) in my opinion you don't need a caption for anything that follows the flow of the text where you can just describe it in the preceding text. A caption makes immediately sense if the object has to be looked for first (a *Konsultationsobjekt*). I *know* that people insist of giving captions to non-floating objects (which is the reason for `\captionof`). I admit that there are exceptions to the rule, though. (I never had one in any of my documents…)

Comment: I still disagree but remain silent on this from now. You, see, taunting on banalities can be troublesome ;-)

Comment: It will not float away if you use \begin{table}[H] ....

Comment: @exchange it will not float either if you use `\begin{center}` (and `\captionof{table}{...}` from the `caption` package - this would be my preferred solution) :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variant for not misusing the `table` environment (in my point of view it's no table!) but using a new 'float' type `enumcnt` and applying `\captionof` for this.

If `cleveref` is used, the settings have to be adapted of course.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{enumcnt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={List}]{enumcnt}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate} \captionof{enumcnt}{List of steps needed to be taken}\label{dolist}
  \item Do A.
  \item Do B.
  \item Do C.
\end{enumerate}

As seen in List \ref{dolist}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following emulates the tiny [`capt-of` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) to set the appropriate caption type *inside* the `enumerate` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{%
  \def\@captype{table}% Emulate capt-of package
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \caption{List of steps needed to be taken}\label{dolist}
  \item Do A.
  \item Do B.
  \item Do C.
\end{enumerate}

As seen in Table~\ref{dolist}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Load package `caption` and than instead `\caption{...}` use `\captionof{table}{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate} \captionof{table}{List of steps needed to be taken}\label{dolist}
  \item Do A.
  \item Do B.
  \item Do C.
\end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: An underrated solution (yet)!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, :-)-. It seems that I'm steel clumsy and slow in my answer. My decisions, when to write only comment with (obvious) solution or formulate an answer (regardless if it has only one line of text) still make me troubles. Even worse, in transforming of my comments to answer I many times  unwise  erase comment after then ...